# Automatically retrived data from Xero into Excel

Tags: excel, oauth-2.0, xero-api

I had previously managed to establish a connection to Xero's API using iOCDB manager, where I could get data into Excel from Xero. This was possible while Xero still used oAuth 1, but since this is no longer possible I am struggling with oAuth 2.

Would anybody please be able to guide me in the right direction how I can begin to set this up? There is some data in Xero that I need to export into Excel and I need to automate this process (In general I am looking to have all my Account Transactions up to date in Excel).

My coding knowledge is not very good, but if I am on the right path I am hoping with a lot of questions and help I can get something working.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of our certified integrations that sync with excel https://apps.xero.com/us/search?q=excel

Or google sheets https://apps.xero.com/us/search?q=google%20sheets